# Import object without bpy.ops.wm.link_append

Tags: python

Is it possible to import an object from a library file through Python without using `bpy.ops.wm.link_append`? I want an object to appear in `bpy.data.objects` without updating current scene.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Blender 2.72, there are two separate operators:

- `bpy.ops.wm.link()`
- `bpy.ops.wm.append()`

Apart from operators, there's also a lower-level API to import datablocks (selectively) from .blends: [bpy.data.libraries.load()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html)

The docs include a few examples how you can use this function.

Comment: +1. It seems that `bpy.ops.wm.link()` doesn't support wildcard (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69985/link-all-objects-meshes-and-materials-from-another-file-with-wildcard)? As a workaround, I used the code by @der_die_das_jojo, but that actually appends everything over, although the name is `scn.objects.link()`... Any better ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example how to use [bpy.data.libraries.load()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html) and [link](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects) it to current scene

```
import bpy
scn = bpy.context.scene
filepath = "D:\\File.blend"

#append object from .blend file
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = data_from.objects

#link object to current scene
for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
        scn.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: I often get `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` on line: `scn.objects.link(obj)`. It occurs randomly but almost on every other attempt.