# How to Link/Append a data-block using the Python API?

Tags: python, append

I'm searching a way to append a group in Python.

It should behave exactly like the *Append* function (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) works, all objects should be local and editable. The idea is to append a character (with rig etc.) via Python and not *Link* it (to be able to modify it without making everything local one by one).

Thanks

Comment: Would you know ahead of time the blend file and path, as well as the exact group name that you want to append? Or do you need some type of browsing interface?

Comment: I already know blend, path and group name

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a solution. It appends an instance of the **group** (Blender 2.7x only):

```
import bpy

filepath = "/path/to/file.blend"
group_name = "CubeGroup"

# append, set to true to keep the link to the original file
link = False 

# append all groups from the .blend file
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_src, data_dst):
    ## all groups
    # data_to.groups = data_from.groups

    # only append a single group we already know the name of
    data_dst.groups = [group_name]

# add the group instance to the scene
for group in data_dst.groups:
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(group.name, None)
    ob.dupli_group = group
    ob.dupli_type = 'GROUP'
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob) # Blender 2.7x
```

*Credit: solution is based on this answer: [Import object without bpy.ops.wm.link_append](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/import-object-without-bpy-ops-wm-link-append)*

---

It's basically the same for **objects**:

```
import bpy

# path to the blend
filepath = "/path/to/file.blend"

# name of object(s) to append or link
obj_name = "Cube"

# append, set to true to keep the link to the original file
link = False

# link all objects starting with 'Cube'
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith(obj_name)]

#link object to current scene
for obj in data_to.objects:
    if obj is not None:
       #bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj) # Blender 2.7x
       bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj) # Blender 2.8x
```

As of Blender 2.8 *groups* have been replaced by the new [**collection system**](https://code.blender.org/2018/05/collections-and-groups/):

```
import bpy

# path to the blend
filepath = "/path/to/file.blend"

# name of collection(s) to append or link
coll_name = "MyCollection"

# append, set to true to keep the link to the original file
link = False

# link all collections starting with 'MyCollection'
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c.startswith(coll_name)]

# link collection to scene collection
for coll in data_to.collections:
    if coll is not None:
       bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
```

Further information: https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html

Comment: Sorry but this don't make it. This is the solution i have already, that's why i specified "behave like the append operator(shift F1) with everything local/editable".
Here it behave like a link (ctrl alt o). i ll edit my first post to be more clear

Comment: @Boris, There is a `link` argument, Set it to `False` to behave like **Append**

Comment: In Blender 2.8 replace `bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)` with `bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)`

Comment: @brockmann   Re edit, TM chose tthe one? datablock type that has changed... groups become collections to make it 2.8+ compatico.

Comment: Ooops, thanks @batFINGER Added a collection example

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Blender 4? My old way no longer works.