# How to append a Rig with a python interface at the same time

Tags: python, rigging

I'm making a rig that has a python interface and I was wondering if their was anyway to append the rig and the script at the same time so the script runs as soon as it's appended.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this manually, you need to run the script after it is linked. The script auto-runs only on file open/reload (if it is registered).

You can write an addon, that will link your character, create proxy rig from it, link the script and run the script:

- [Here is how you link stuff with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api)
- You make proxy rig like this:

  ```
  # get your linked group object
  objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
  group_ob = objects.get('Character')   # <- you probably have this from linking already
  # create proxy rig
  objects.active = group_ob
  bpy.ops.object.proxy_make()
  # get the proxy object if you need
  proxy_ob = bpy.context.active_object
  ```
- Running the script is easy:

  ```
  script = bpy.data.texts.get("rig_script.py")   # <- you have this from linking
  exec(script.as_string())
  ```