# How to Link/Append world using the blender Python API?

Tags: python, append

I'm searching a way to append a World in blender Python.
I read the reference in [How to Link/Append a data-block using the Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api) but that is for group append.
is there a way to make that work for world append.

sorry for rip english

Comment: In the [accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34543/15543) to linked question above quote _"It's basically the same for objects"_  It's basically the same for worlds

Comment: I figured out after squeezing my brain.. thank you for the answer

Comment: @ahmad any chance for comment with explanation how ? I did the same thing as I do with lights/matterials but no luck.