# How to Link/Append collections from a different blender file in 2.8

Tags: python, append

im trying to link some collections from python, and i was following the example from this post : [How to Link/Append a data-block using the Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api)

but its not for 2.8 and it uses groups, how can i implement something like this in 2.8?
Kind Regards
Andre