# I have error in my python code(while producing a blender addon) which i couldn't figure it out. Can anyone please help me out?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error, append

So, recently I was planning on creating a 3D model pack for blender 2.9 in which my 3d models can be easily accessible within blender through addon. My plan was to make a small little tool shelf (at the right panel) in which it shows preview image of the 3D model and when I click add button after selecting the desired 3D model from preview, it should append the object. [image: This is the Style of blender addon.]

As you can see it has categories and there are two categories and the previews are working fine.

My problem is:

When I click on Add button it suddenly pops up  with an error message which is given down below:
[image]

and I can't figure it out for a long time why it happens since I am a beginner in the field of coding.
I just reached till to this point by seeking help from others. I will provide the code of the addon so that if anyone could help me I would appreciate that. Thank you!

[LINK OF CODE AND FILE STRUCTURE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G1-JeIXlAeoCQsC2WP-iJRLgvEZKAbRm?usp=sharing)

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38060/how-to-link-append-with-a-python-script

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I cant figure out the solution to my problem. Each time I update the code it shows the same error. What should I do?

Comment: I would recommend playing around with bpy.ops.wm.append() operator alone to figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: Can you (or someone who knows) somehow help me with this by editing the code I have been given? Five days have passed and still I couldn't figure out the solution yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a path error, similar to what is described in this question.

[Append python script for Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145174/append-python-script-for-blender-2-8)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will check it out and I hope this works out.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I cant figure out the solution to my problem. Each time I update the code it shows the same error. What should I do?

Comment: Does it matter that the error isn't seeing '/light.blend', just '/light'

Comment: I have no idea. Each time I add [+ ".blend"] extension to the last, it jumps to previous path (wall_lights.blend) which is a folder name.