# How to get a blend file from a link and append it using blender python?

Tags: python, scripting, append

I want to be able to have a python script append a blender file from a link that it is housed in. I have the .blend file on my website and I want to be able to grab it from blender, and append it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Everything? Related: [How to Link/Append a data-block using the Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34543/31447)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant link as in website link like example.com link

Comment: No problem. Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python Otherwise I'd suggest share the current state of your code, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Than you Brockmann!