# How to switch to "active" after append?

Tags: python, append

When I try to use `bpy.ops.wm.append`, the object appears "selected" with the red outline, but how do I switch it to "Active" with yellow outline?

```
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath="Prefab_Objects.blend",
    directory="/Users/Yuri/Desktop/Blender_Python_Test/Prefab_Objects.blend\\Object\\",
    filename="tower")
```

(I need to apply `bpy.context.active_object.name` afterward, but can’t because the object is not "active")

Comment: The recommended way is to use [BlendDataLibraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html) Have a look into: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the active object with this command:

```
If len(bpy.context.selected_objects):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
```

The active object is now reachable by:

```
active_obj = bpy.context.active_object
```

Comment: Thank you! ```bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]``` is working!