# With python how do I append cameras and lights from another file?

Tags: python, append

I am trying to append cameras and lights from one .blend file to another, like this:

```
with bpy.data.libraries.load(os.path.abspath(camera_file), link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
    print("Importing cameras %s" % (", ").join(data_from.cameras))
    print("Importing light %s" % (", ").join(data_from.lights))

    data_to.cameras = data_from.cameras
    data_to.light   = data_from.lights
```

The lists of cameras and lights are output correctly but nothing seems to happen.

What am I doing wrong? I think I should probably import camera and light objects too as objects - but how do I do that?

Comment: @Duarte: I think Simone wants a python solution...

Comment: Without Python or without Simone needs be linking *Objects*, not cameras and lights as in the linked duplicate. We already have plenty of answers covering linking with python https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/how-to-link-append-a-data-block-using-the-python-api

Comment: Then I would recommend linking that python solution 