# Define directly filepath of wm.append command?

Tags: python

Is it possible to define the .blend path in the wm.append command to open directly in the selected blend file ?

Comment: Yes, I can't test it at the moment, but [**this**](https://gist.github.com/p2or/8e09c9b388a420b453a0601c5f3a14da) should work platform  independent. Alternatively you can use `bpy.data.libraries.load` (lower-level API) for this as mentioned here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/import-object-without-bpy-ops-wm-link-append

Comment: I can't use bpy.data.libraries.load because i need to keep the UI interface to keep the choise to the users which library and which data he wants to append. I tried with bpy.ops.wm.append('INVOKE_DEFAULT', directory = my_blend_path). it works but if I append another with a different path , and then I try again with my custom directory, the append concerve the last path used . So is it possible to reset the previous append path before add my custom directory ?